# How do I resolve 404 error returned by request.GetResponse() when trying to create a media library item via Sitecore Web API?

Tags: sitecore-api

I am trying to create items in my Sitecore Media libary via Sitecore Web API. Our version of Sitecore is 8.2. My main concern is if I am formulating the request properly and if there is a place like my my "showConfig.aspx" that can give me instruction guidance. Here is my code ...

Console app: Main

```
PostMediaItem();
```

Here is the PostMediaItem:

```
 public static void PostMediaItem()
        {
            // Potentially could be used in our console app

            string HOST = @"https://intranet-dev.university.edu";
            string ParentID = "{2260D52E-74AA-46D4-864B-701C82D49B6D}";         //Must be media library folder/item. this is the root
            string mediaFileExt = ".pdf";                                       //you need to specify the extension. You can get that by the content-type returned or the way you find better.

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf");
            HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream mediaStream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();


            //create a instance and inform the credentials as well the host
            MediaPost mp = new MediaPost(HOST, @"sitecore\ad\UserName", "Password1");

            //post the media!
            //Important: It needs a Valid Item Name,
            //                    a Valid Parent ID under Media Library,
            //                    the database, the stream and the extension
            mp.PostMedia("Class List", new Guid(ParentID), "master", mediaStream, mediaFileExt);


        }
```

Class: MediaPost

```
 public class MediaPost
    {
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public MediaPost(string host, string username, string password)
        {
            this.Host = host;
            this.Username = username;
            this.Password = password;
        }
        public void PostMedia(string itemName, Guid parentId, string databaseName, Stream fileStream, string fileExtension)
        {
            //create the url
            string url = String.Format("{0}/-/item/v1/?", this.Host.TrimEnd('/'));
            //append parameters
            url += String.Format("name={0}&sc_itemid={1}&sc_database={2}&payload=content"
              , HttpUtility.UrlEncode(itemName)
              , HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parentId.ToString())
              , HttpUtility.UrlEncode(databaseName));
            //create request instance
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            //headers
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Username", this.Username);
            request.Headers.Add("X-Scitemwebapi-Password", this.Password);
            //apply content type and boundary
            string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            byte[] boundaryBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                //boundary
                stream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
                //file header
                string header = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + itemName + fileExtension + "\"\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\n\r\n";
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                //file bytes
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                int bytesRead;
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    // upload from a given stream
                    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                byte[] end = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
                stream.Write(end, 0, end.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
            //send post
            request.GetResponse();
        }
    }
```

When I run it, this is what the URL looks like:

```
https://intranet-dev.univeristy.edu/-/item/v1/?name=Class%20List&sc_itemid=2260d52e-74aa-46d4-864b-701c82d49b6d&sc_database=master&payload=content
```

Our Intranet address is:

https://intranet-dev.universtiy.edu

and I keep getting the error:

[image]

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please use the ItemService for Sitecore 8.2. More info at https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf

Comment: I was just reading about this. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using previous Sitecore Item Web Api, use the latest ItemService REST API which supports Sitecore versions 7.5+. More information about the ItemService can be found at [Developer's Guide to Sitecore.Services.Client](https://doc.sitecore.com/sdnarchive/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf).

The whole documentation on the Developer's Guide is based on Javascript code snippet and based on your question, you are using a console C# app to create item. Below is a code snippet example on how to implement creation of item in C#.

**Model for Authentication**

```
public class Authentication
{
    [JsonProperty("domain")]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Model for Item to create**

```
public class ItemRequest
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public string TemplateID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Console Main Implementation**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var authUrl = "https://<domain>/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login";
        var authData = new Authentication
        {
            Domain = "sitecore",
            Username = "admin",
            Password = "b"
        };

        var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authUrl);

        authRequest.Method = "POST";
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        var requestAuthBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authData);

        var authDatas = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestAuthBody);

        using (var dataStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(authDatas, 0, authDatas.Length);
        }

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        authRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        var authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine($"Login Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)authResponse).StatusDescription}");

        authResponse.Close();

        var emailObj = new ItemRequest
        {
            ItemName = "Test APi 4",
            TemplateID = "{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}",
            Title = "Test API TITLE",
            Text = "TEST API TEXT"
        };

        var url = "https://<domain>/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fcontent%2Fhome";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;

        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailObj);

        var data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestBody);

        using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine($"Item Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred. Message: {ex.Message}.\r\n StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}.\r\n InnerException: {ex.InnerException}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Outcome**

[image]

**Notes**

1. A cookie container is created so that after the authentication, the next requests can validate whether the request can create the item or returns a `403 Forbidden Status` .
2. I had to update the setting `Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy` to set it as `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure`. The `ServicesOnPolicy` allows access to all Entity and Item Services.
3. Authentication URL should be on HTTPS.

Comment: So, I did use your code snippet from above, I read the documentation in the guide "Sitecore.Services.Client". It seems I am almost there, I did update the Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy to ServicesOnPolicy but I am still receiving an Internal Services Error 500. I checked the logs, but I didn't find anything use there.

Comment: If you are getting error 500 it may be that it is creating an item with same name twice

Comment: i will continue to focus on this again today. It isn't the item it is trying to create because it is failing on the getResponse() line. I will try to figure this out. thanks

Comment: Is it the first getResponse that is failing?

Comment: yes, the first getRepsonse is failing, that is where I am trying to focus right now. looking at the exception, no inner exception, and nothing that is standing out as an error. I do know my user id and password works. thanks for all of your help

Comment: so, I figured out the error it is a Protocol Error ... The requested resource can only be accessed through SSL ... so at least I can try to research what is going on with my Infrastructure group.

Comment: well my URL is HTTPS and I am accessing an HTTPS enabled site. but I will review. And once I get this working, I will completely upvote and approve. I know how important that is. Thank you so much